# how fix image in parent div with responsive content with remain Aspect ratio?

Tags: html, responsive-design

i have two div in my html page like this image.
[image]

main div with background image has responsive technology. i have second div with face picture  as main div content that show in above picture with red border, which its resizing should be correspond to the main div background in a way that it's Aspect ratio remains last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://f6design.com/journal/2011/10/18/responsive-elements-that-retain-their-aspect-ratio/

You have to manipulate the padding property on the parent div to get the desired effect of retaining the aspect-ratio. If you show me your code from some live website, I can further pin-point where you need to make the changes in your CSS.